# Disable pagination tooltip buttons (first, last, page numbers(1, 2, 3)) in Tabulator JS

Tags: javascript, pagination, tabulator

I need only the **previous and next buttons** on my table for pagination. I don't need (first, last, page numbers(1, 2, 3)) buttons. Is there any way to disable these pagination buttons similar to enabling/disabling paginationCounter? I'm using tabulator.js for my table implementation.

[image]

**Reference:**

1. http://tabulator.info/docs/5.3/page#overview
2. https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator

```js
//define data array
var tabledata = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Oli Bob',
    progress: 12,
    gender: 'male',
    rating: 1,
    col: 'red',
    dob: '19/02/1984',
    car: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Mary May',
    progress: 1,
    gender: 'female',
    rating: 2,
    col: 'blue',
    dob: '14/05/1982',
    car: true,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Christine Lobowski',
    progress: 42,
    gender: 'female',
    rating: 0,
    col: 'green',
    dob: '22/05/1982',
    car: 'true',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Brendon Philips',
    progress: 100,
    gender: 'male',
    rating: 1,
    col: 'orange',
    dob: '01/08/1980',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Margret Marmajuke',
    progress: 16,
    gender: 'female',
    rating: 5,
    col: 'yellow',
    dob: '31/01/1999',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Frank Harbours',
    progress: 38,
    gender: 'male',
    rating: 4,
    col: 'red',
    dob: '12/05/1966',
    car: 1,
  },
];

var table = new Tabulator('#example-table', {
  data: tabledata, //load row data from array
  layout: 'fitColumns', //fit columns to width of table
  responsiveLayout: 'hide', //hide columns that dont fit on the table
  tooltips: true, //show tool tips on cells
  addRowPos: 'top', //when adding a new row, add it to the top of the table
  history: true, //allow undo and redo actions on the table
  pagination: 'local', //paginate the data
  paginationSize: 2, //allow 7 rows per page of data
  paginationCounter: 'rows', //display count of paginated rows in footer
  movableColumns: true, //allow column order to be changed
  initialSort: [
    //set the initial sort order of the data
    { column: 'name', dir: 'asc' },
  ],
  columns: [
    //define the table columns
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name', editor: 'input' },
    {
      title: 'Task Progress',
      field: 'progress',
      hozAlign: 'left',
      formatter: 'progress',
      editor: true,
    },
    {
      title: 'Gender',
      field: 'gender',
      width: 95,
      editor: 'select',
      editorParams: { values: ['male', 'female'] },
    },
    {
      title: 'Rating',
      field: 'rating',
      formatter: 'star',
      hozAlign: 'center',
      width: 100,
      editor: true,
    },
    { title: 'Color', field: 'col', width: 130, editor: 'input' },
    {
      title: 'Date Of Birth',
      field: 'dob',
      width: 130,
      sorter: 'date',
      hozAlign: 'center',
    },
    {
      title: 'Driver',
      field: 'car',
      width: 90,
      hozAlign: 'center',
      formatter: 'tickCross',
      sorter: 'boolean',
      editor: true,
    },
  ],
});
```

```html
<html>
  <link
    href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <body>
    <div id="example-table"></div>
  </body>

  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"
  ></script>
  <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To disable paginationButtonCount, simply set it to 0.
- To disable the First and Last buttons take the CSS approach and set display as none
  for these two buttons.

```js
//define data array
var tabledata = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Oli Bob',
    progress: 12,
    gender: 'male',
    rating: 1,
    col: 'red',
    dob: '19/02/1984',
    car: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Mary May',
    progress: 1,
    gender: 'female',
    rating: 2,
    col: 'blue',
    dob: '14/05/1982',
    car: true,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Christine Lobowski',
    progress: 42,
    gender: 'female',
    rating: 0,
    col: 'green',
    dob: '22/05/1982',
    car: 'true',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Brendon Philips',
    progress: 100,
    gender: 'male',
    rating: 1,
    col: 'orange',
    dob: '01/08/1980',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Margret Marmajuke',
    progress: 16,
    gender: 'female',
    rating: 5,
    col: 'yellow',
    dob: '31/01/1999',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Frank Harbours',
    progress: 38,
    gender: 'male',
    rating: 4,
    col: 'red',
    dob: '12/05/1966',
    car: 1,
  },
];

var table = new Tabulator('#example-table', {
  data: tabledata, //load row data from array
  layout: 'fitColumns', //fit columns to width of table
  responsiveLayout: 'hide', //hide columns that dont fit on the table
  addRowPos: 'top', //when adding a new row, add it to the top of the table
  history: true, //allow undo and redo actions on the table
  pagination: 'local', //paginate the data
  paginationSize: 2, //allow 7 rows per page of data
  paginationButtonCount: 0,
  paginationCounter: 'rows', //display count of paginated rows in footer
  movableColumns: true, //allow column order to be changed
  initialSort: [
    //set the initial sort order of the data
    { column: 'name', dir: 'asc' },
  ],
  columns: [
    //define the table columns
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name', editor: 'input' },
    {
      title: 'Task Progress',
      field: 'progress',
      hozAlign: 'left',
      formatter: 'progress',
      editor: true,
    },
    {
      title: 'Gender',
      field: 'gender',
      width: 95,
      editor: 'select',
      editorParams: { values: ['male', 'female'] },
    },
    {
      title: 'Rating',
      field: 'rating',
      formatter: 'star',
      hozAlign: 'center',
      width: 100,
      editor: true,
    },
    { title: 'Color', field: 'col', width: 130, editor: 'input' },
    {
      title: 'Date Of Birth',
      field: 'dob',
      width: 130,
      sorter: 'date',
      hozAlign: 'center',
    },
    {
      title: 'Driver',
      field: 'car',
      width: 90,
      hozAlign: 'center',
      formatter: 'tickCross',
      sorter: 'boolean',
      editor: true,
    },
  ],
});
```

```css
.tabulator-page[data-page='first'], .tabulator-page[data-page='last'] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <link
    href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <body>
    <div id="example-table"></div>
  </body>

  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"
  ></script>
  <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
</html>
```